# Dojo's New Dgrid with a non-REST store

Tags: rest, dojo, query-string, dgrid

I would like to use Dojo's dgrid to replace a YUI data grid in a project I am working on. Presently, I feed data into the YUI widget using query string data, not a REST-based arrangement. I would like to continue using the query string to convey information rather than implementing a new REST-based backend, but all of the dgrid information I find seems to point to using REST. Is it possible to use something like the seemingly depreciated QueryStore? The last time I tried to implement something with Dojo without using the REST based data store, I did not fare well, particularly once I got to trying to deal with lazy loading.

Comment: what about ObjectStore with Memory store? You can do XHRs to fill in memory store and then use ObjectStore to popluate grid.